# Java SWT how to determine a widget editable

Tags: java, swt

I was wondering how to check if a widget is a Button or a Text? How should I do that? By using `widget.getClass().getName()` and compare the string equals to `"org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo"`? Is there any example or sample code demonstrate this? I would like to check if a widget is an editable widget (Text, Spinner, Combo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately in SWT editable widget classes don't implement any common interface. If this feature is important to you implement your own interface:

```
public interface Editable{
    public void comommonEditableMethod(Param param); 
}
```

Then your own widgets from SWT that you want in "editable" group:

```
public class MyText extends Text implements Editable {...
public class MyCombo extends Combo implements Editable {...
```

etc...
Then in code you can check:

```
if(myControl instanceof Editable) {
    // do something
}
```

Just remember to override Widget's method in every SWT control you subclass, or you will get nasty exception:

```
@Override
protected void checkSubclass () {
    //DISABLE SUBCLASS CHECK
}
```

Comment: can I just check the class name? It seems to be one of the approach, though probably not so elegant...

Comment: What do you want to do with editable controls if they don't share any interface? If you want just change background or font checking class name/type is ok, otherwise my approach provide more generic way to solve your problem.

Comment: I want to activate/deactivate context when focus in/out editable controls. So no need direct access to the controls.

Comment: If you want to check widget class use instanceof for example: if(myControl instanceof Text) { //this is text control };

Comment: But we need to create subclasses of standard SWT classes ONLY for the purpose to check whether Control is Editable or not !!!!!!!

Comment: Don't be rude. Don't use exclamation mark. I provide clean and elegant solution for this problem. Is much better than comparing class name to every possible editable control, or to instanceofing all of them.

Answer (score -1):

`Button` is non scrollable and `Text`,`Spinner`,`Combo` all are scrollable.But all these are sub class of `Control`.
Refer the below screen shot and modify the text code(`Main` class) according to your need. Important is to understand the `Widget` class type hierarchy.

[image]